# Any antonyms of be?

Tags: antonyms, be

Is there any word that is the opposite of the verb, "**be**?" That is, the state of not existing?

Several thesauruses give answers related to the *termination* of existence -- die, cease, desist, ebb, stop -- but I haven't found a single word that indicates something does not exist and never has existed.

"My ambition died that day," implies that you once had ambition.

"My ambition is absent," perhaps avoids the terminal aspect of existance. But it shows that there is an ambition, and that it is doing (being) something. It is being absent.

"I lack ambition," is more to the point, but is more about someone possessing (or not possessing) a thing than the existence of the thing.

How could you say, "National ambition nonexists," with a verb expressing the non existence of the thing?

Do any other languages have a word like this?

It troubles me that the most fundamental verb in English -- perhaps the most essential *word* in English -- does not have a proper antonym. Even The Bard came up short in his immortal question, "To be, or not to be?"

Help me, please, that I may sleep tonight.

Comment: If we've gotten this far without one, it may be hard to make a case in favor. This may be analogous to thinking the sightless "see" black. They just don't see. Something may just not be. Something we can conceive of, like perpetual motion, may just *not exist*.

Comment: What is the antonym of a unicorn?

Comment: A unicorn that has lost its corn is obviously a popcorn.

Comment: The use of 'the most fundamental verb in English' is contentious. The existential usage is rare; auxiliary and copular usages are far more common. The opposite of 'It is coming tomorrow' is 'It is not coming tomorrow', and the opposites of 'It is here / cold' are 'It is not here / cold'. Other opposites can be formed here by switching lexical verbs or adjectives: 'It is staying away tomorrow' / 'It is absent / hot'.

Answer (score 3):

There is no antonym. If there were, Shakespeare would not have given Prince Hamlet the immortal line: “To be or not to be, that is the question…”. Hamlet, Act 3, Scene 1.

In fact, one could even argue that the impact of this line on popular culture has prevented an antonym from emerging. It has in effect been *barded* from the language.

The line even has its own Wikipedia page, where you can read about how Shakespeare’s English has influenced others, including the creators of a Klingon language for Star Trek.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_be,_or_not_to_be

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll take the bait. The closest verb we have to an *anti-be*, *not-be*, or *pseudo-exist* is

**imagine** (v.)

> To represent to oneself in imagination; to form a mental image of,
> picture to oneself (**something not real** or not present to the senses)
> OED

Because we are looking for a verb, we'll need  **subjects** for it, *or what's the point*? Of course we're not talking about imagining (picturing) real things, like tigers and tiger lilies. So the *subject* of our *not-be* (i.e. something that can *be* this *not-be*) can't be anything that exists. Or rather, it can "exist," but only in our imagination, our speech, our folklore and fiction, etc.—an imagined reality.

To talk about something that not-is we have to give it properties and, usually, a name, *otherwise all non-existent things are alike*. Assigning names and properties to non-existent (imaginary) things is the rightful job of the imagination.

We do say that when something dies, is destroyed, or perishes it ceases to exist (at least on Earth), or its atoms are returned to the stockpile, but I believe we're talking about either side of existence, when something simply...isn't.

Nevertheless, for imaginary things, we're perfectly happy to use our *to be*.

*There are fairies at the bottom of my garden.*

Comment: I'm not convinced that copular verbs can even **have** antonyms. We used to use negative proclitics in English for all kinds of verbs that would fuse into the front (hence my earlier snark, as in *will he or nill he*), but today our negative clitics are enclitics fusing on the other end. The opposite of *is* quite simply is *isn't*, which is a verb in its own right as can be trivially proven by how it moves *en masse* under inversion. That's why the modern antonym of *will* is *won't* now not *nill* (outside of frozen phrases) anymore.

Comment: And we'd be hard-pressed to come up with anything shorter than *isn't*, and ease of typing is what it's all about. Don't we *think of* and use *isn't* as as if it were a single verb?

Comment: Can copula verbs have antonyms? Some languages such as Chinese can replace a copula with a word meaning "not" to negate a sentence. Although it's a stretch to call such words antonyms.